# Where to multiply the inverse of the eigenvector matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $PDP^{-1}=P^{-1}DP$ true if $P$ is the matrix with eigenvectors in columns and $D$ the matrix with eigenvalues in the diagonal?

Comment: $P$ is the matrix with eigenvectors in columns.. whose eigen vectors?... $D$ the matrix with eigenvalues in the diagonal.. whose eigen values?

Comment: It seems to me that this only holds when P is orthogonal.

Comment: It holds when $P$ is involutory, i.e., $P^2 = I$. For example, when $P$ is a reflector.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true, as a counter example take a matrix in $\mathrm{SO}(2)$:

$$\mathbf{R}(\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) & -\sin(\varphi) \\
\sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$$

This decomposes as: $\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}^{\dagger}$, with $\mathbf{P}$ being the unitary matrix with eigenvectors as it's spanning columns:

$$\mathbf{P}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ i & -i\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \mathbf{\Lambda}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\varphi} & 0 \\
0 & e^{i\varphi}\end{pmatrix}$$

If we then compute the product $\mathbf{P}^{\dagger}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}$, we get:

$$\mathbf{P}^{\dagger}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) & -i\sin(\varphi) \\
-i\sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$$

Which is not equal to $\mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to see when 
$$ P^{-1} D P = P D P^{-1}$$

Your statement would be true if and ony if $P^2$ and $D$ commute i.e. $P^2\cdot D=D\cdot P^2$.

If the diagonal elements of $D$ are distinct (all different) then $P^2$ has to be diagonal.

Note that $P^2$ commuting with $D$ is not the same as $P$ commuting with $D$. Consider for example
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & -\alpha\end{pmatrix},~~~ \alpha^2+\beta \gamma \ne 0$$
Show that your result is true no matter what $D$ is